# Left Join Where Clause - How to return a default value when null

Tags: sql-server, default

Im trying to get a default value when no results are returned. The example im using is im left joining table 1 to table 2 Where the userid = 1. As you can see ted doesnt have a photo in table 2.

Instead of returning nothing in sql server I want it to return No Photo Found.

**This is the code im using but it doesnt return the default value.**

```
SELECT 
  ISNULL(photoName, 'No Photos Found') as photoName 
FROM usertable
LEFT OUTER JOIN
phototable
ON
usertable.id= phototable.id
WHERE userID = 1
```

**User Table**

```
Id | User
0  | Jack
```

**Photo Table**

```
ID | Photo
0  | me.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight typo in your pasted query:

```
as (photoName
```

Should be:

```
as photoName

SELECT 
  ISNULL(photoName, 'No Photos Found') as photoName, 
FROM usertable
LEFT OUTER JOIN
phototable
ON
usertable.id= phototable.id
WHERE userID = 1;
```

Besides that your code looks ok, so do you have real data instead of your posted data, because it is most likely a data/schema issue.

In your sample data you call the column photo instead of photoname for example.

Comment: Sorry your right i made a bit of a mistake. So lets say that both tables dont have a reference on the join. I revised the example and took the reference  with the id of 1 out of the user table. How can i get a default result if no match is found for example there is no userID with 1?

Comment: If there is no match at all (userId=1 is no there at all), then no records are returned, so no is the answer on that one.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT coalesce(p.photoName, 'No Photos Found') as photoName
FROM usertable u LEFT OUTER JOIN
     phototable p
     ON u.id = p.id
WHERE u.userID = 1
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why COALESCE over ISNULL, when there are only two params (other than it's part of the standard, and ISNULL isn't) - knowing that COALESCE is no more than a shorthand for CASE, with all it's baggage?

Comment: `coalesce()` is ANSI standard so it is supported in almost all databases, and I tend to lean toward standard functionality when other options are essentially equal.   `isnull()` does have a performance advantage when the first argument is complex (such as a subquery), so I would use it then.